# LCD show different float number

Tags: floating-point, arduino, microcontroller, lcd, arduino-uno

I'm developing system that will showing output on LCD. 
I declare variable data type as float, but the LCD display showing **0.00** that I don't initialize, because I declare it with **0.0**
I want the LCD display showing **0.000**, but whatever I try to change the initialize value the LCD Display always showing **0.00**
.So, how I can make the LCD Display showing **0.000**
[This is the link for the image](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-5A6mLbGHJtE/U_a4_ui-DHI/AAAAAAAAA64/bPgO9HVNjNI/w480-h360-no/lcddd.jpg)
Below are my code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

volatile int NbTopsFan;
float flowrate = 0.0;
float volume = 0.0;
int hallSensor = 2;


LiquidCrystal lcd (12, 11, 9, 8, 7, 6);
void rpm() {
  NbTopsFan++;
}

void setup(){
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (hallSensor, INPUT);
  Serial.begin (9600);
  attachInterrupt (0, rpm, RISING);

  lcd.begin (16, 2);
  lcd.clear ();
}
void loop (){
  digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
  NbTopsFan=0;
  sei();
  delay(1000);
  cli();
  flowrate = NbTopsFan / 7.5;
  volume += (flowrate / 60);



  lcd.clear ();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("flow :");
  lcd.print(flowrate);
  lcd.print("L/m");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("VOl :");
  lcd.print(volume);
  lcd.print("L");

  Serial.print("Pulse");
  Serial.print(NbTopsFan);
  Serial.print(flowrate);
  Serial.print("L/m");
  Serial.print(volume,4);
  Serial.print("liter");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

According to the documentation of [Print](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print), to specify the number of decimal places to be used, a second parameter is needed. So in you example you could use

```
lcd.print(flowrate,4);
```

and

```
 lcd.print(volume,4);
```

Comment: ok, thank you for the answer, but when I try to use  Sertial.println(volume,4);  why cann't show same case?..  <br>what should I do...